# Injective maps between finite sets must be bijections

Tags: functional-analysis, real-analysis

> Let A, B be finite sets, and suppose that there exist injective maps f: A $\rightarrow$ B and g: B $\rightarrow$ A. Prove that f and g must be bijective.

It appears to be really intuitive to me but I just cannot get the last bit solved.
I have tried 2 approaches, and here are some sketch:

1. Pick $a_1$, $a_2$ from A ($a_1 \neq a_2$), then pick some $b_1$ such that $f(a_1) = b_1$, and pick some $b_2$ that $f(a_2) = b_2$. Because f is bijective, so $b_1 != b_2$. Then pick $a_3, a_4$ such that $a_3 = g(b_1)$ and $a_4 = g(b_2)$, and by the same bijectivity $a3 != a_4$. Yet I cannot loop the logic back to proof that $a_1 = a_3$ or $a_2 = a_4$...
2. I tried to proof g(f(x)) is injective. Pick $g(f(x_1)) = g(f(x_2)$. By injectivity, then $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$, and again by injectivity, $x_1 = x_2$. Then I have no idea how to proceed...

Hopefully the explanation of my thoughts make some sense. Any help/advice would be appreciate since I am still very new to all of this.

Comment: It would really help to know what definition of "finite set" you are using.

Comment: You are not using the finiteness.  You need to since it is not true if the sets are not finite.  Pigeons might be useful.

Comment: (1) is just a huge mess. As a general rule, you can't go too far in a proof if you do not separate the hypothesis from the thesis. Children sometimes do this thing where they read the problem, then they list the DATA on one side and the QUESTIONS on the other. It works just as well with hypothesis and thesis respectively.

Comment: What are you assuming and what are you proving?

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio You are very right that this a huge mess. I am really new to doing all sort of proofs so apologize for naïve expressions and logics...?

Comment: @badjohn For complicated reasons I have not touched pigeons as I technically should...I would check that topic out. Thanks!

Comment: You should still give us your definition of finite set, since that's a critical part of the proof. For instance, if you say that finite means "every injection from the set to itself is a bijection", then the argument will go differently as compared to using the definition "there is a bijection to a natural number" or "the set is not in bijection to any proper subset".

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos so I actually wasn't given one for this question -- but thanks for the explanation, I actually am not aware of the existence of multiple definition of finite set. Apologize for the confusion. I think the definition we had been going with in our course is "there is a bijection to a natural number"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $A, B$ are finite, we can try an argument that uses the sizes of $A$ and $B$.

Here's the key thing you need:

**Lemma:** If $A, B$ are finite sets and $f \colon A \to B$ is an injection, then $|A| \leq |B|$.

**Proof:** Consider the image $f(A)$ of $f$. By definition, $f$ is surjective from $A$ to $f(A)$. Since $f$ is also an injection, $f$ is a bijection from $A$ to $f(A)$, hence $|A| = |f(A)|.$ Since $B$ contains $f(A)$, we must have $|f(A)| \leq B$, so we are done.

Using this, what can you say about $|A|$ and $|B|$ in the original problem? Well, because $f \colon A \to B$ is an injection, we have $|A| \leq |B|$, and since $g \colon B \to A$ is an injection, we have $|B| \leq |A|$. So, we have $|A| = |B|$.

Now, you just need to prove that if $f \colon A \to B$ is an injection and $|A| = |B|$, then $f$ is a bijection. I leave this to you for now. (**Hint:** Think about the size of $|f(A)|$!)

---

Interestingly, a similar fact holds even when $A, B$ aren't finite. If $f \colon A \to B$ and $g \colon B \to A$ are injections, then Cantor-Schroder-Bernstein tells us there must be a bijection between $A$ and $B$, even if $A, B$ are infinite. (One notable difference: the injections $f, g$ themselves might not be bijections.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! It is super helpful and made it much clearer.
Ok so if I am following correctly: so now we have f: A $\rightarrow$ B injection and |A| = |B|. Because as you mentioned f surjective A to f(A), and because f is also injective, there exists a bijection, which |A| = |f(A)| = |B| -- meaning B strictly contains every f(A). This suffice for f to be a bijection..I think?

Comment: @Muuuuuu0829 You're close: you know that $B$ contains $f(A)$, and that $|f(A)| = |B|$. Since $B$ is a finite set, what can we say about $f(A)$ and $B$? Can there be any elements of $B$ that are not in $f(A)$? Once you've answered this, you can then use the fact that $f$ is a surjection from $A$ to $f(A)$.

Comment: Sorry I intuitively understand that there cannot be any elements in B not in f(A) because it is finite, so is bijective to some {1, ..... n} for $n \in N$. So if an elements exist in B but not in f(A) would flip the $|f(A)| = |B|$ balance because (n-1 != n)....?

Comment: @Muuuuuu0829 Yes, exactly!

Comment: thanks a lot! really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $A=\{a_1,\ldots,a_m\}$ and $B=\{b_1,\ldots, b_n\}$ and suppose there exist injective maps $f:A\to B$ and $g:B\to A$.

Assume for a contradiction that $m<n$. So we have
$$ B= \{b_1,\ldots, b_m, b_{m+1},\ldots, b_n\}. $$
If there are $m$ rabbit cages and at least $m+1$ rabbits, then at least two rabbits must be put in the same cage. So $g$ cannot be injective, a contradiction. So it follows that $m=n$ and both $f$ and $g$ must also be surjective.

Comment: So, you've avoided the pigeon hole principle by using the rabbit cage principle - neat.

Comment: oh this is really nice and does make intuitive sense to me. I will probably still use the above one since I will probably use that more in my class, but this is also really nice. Thanks!!!